# CSV Python Outputting: Outputting non-matching field once rather than once for every item in list

Tags: python, csv

I've been trying to figure this out for about a year now and I'm really burnt out on it so please excuse me if this explanation is a bit rough.

I cannot include job data, but it would be accurate to imagine 2 csv files both with the first column populated with values (Serial numbers/phone numbers/names, doesn't matter - just values). Between both csv files, some values would match while other values would only be contained in one or the other (Timmy is in both files and is a match, Robert is only in file 1 and does not match any name in file 2).

I can successfully output a csv value ONCE that exists in the both csv files (I.e. both files contain "Value78", output file will contain "Value78" only once).
When I try to tack on an else statement to my if condition, to handle non-matching items, the program will output 1 entry for every item it does not match with (makes 100% sense, matches happen once but every other comparison result besides the match is a non-match).
I cannot envision a structure or method to hold the fields that don't match back so that they can be output once and not overrun my terminal or output file.

My goal is to output two csv files, matches and non-matches, with the non-matches having only one entry per value.

Anyways, onto the code:

```
import csv

MYUNITS = 'MyUnits.csv'
VENDORUNITS = 'VendorUnits.csv'
MATCHES = 'Matches.csv'
NONMATCHES = 'NonMatches.csv'

with open(MYUNITS,mode='r') as MFile,
open(VENDORUNITS,mode='r') as VFile,
open(MATCHES,mode='w') as OFile,
open(NONMATCHES,mode'w') as NFile:

    MyReader = csv.reader(MFile,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
    MyList = list(MyReader)

    VendorReader = csv.reader(VFile,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
    VList = list(VendorReader)

    for x in range(len(MyList)):
        for y in range(len(VList)):
            if str(MyList[x][0]) == str(VList[y][0]):
                OFile.write(MyList[x][0] + '\n')

            else:
                pass
```

The "else: pass" is where the logic of filtering out non-matches is escaping me. Outputting from this else statement will write the non-matching value (len(VList) - 1) times for an iteration that DOES produce 1 match, the entire len(VList) for an iteration with no match. I've tried using a counter and only outputting if the counter equals the len(VList), (incrementing in the else statement, writing output under the scope of the second for loop), but received the same output as if I tried outputting non-matches.

Comment: Just take it one step at a time first replace `pass` with `NFile.write(MyList[x][0] + '\n')`. Look at the result you get and see if it makes since.

Comment: The issue with this is that my output would still have the same value listed 1000 times for every other item that the comparison failed against.

Comment: One strategy might be to first group them all together and then deduplicate them.

Comment: below I posted an example of adding the non matches to a list, removing the duplicates and then writing it to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I had some issues with my PC. I was able to solve my own question the night I posted. The solution I used is so simple I'm kicking myself for not figuring it out way sooner:

```
import csv

MYUNITS = 'MyUnits.csv'
VENDORUNITS = 'VendorUnits.csv'
MATCHES = 'Matches.csv'
NONMATCHES = 'NonMatches.csv'

with open(MYUNITS,mode='r') as MFile,
open(VENDORUNITS,mode='r') as VFile,
open(MATCHES,mode='w') as OFile,
open(NONMATCHES,mode'w') as NFile:

MyReader = csv.reader(MFile,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
MyList = list(MyReader)

VendorReader = csv.reader(VFile,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
VList = list(VendorReader)

for x in range(len(MyList)):
    tmpStr = ''
    for y in range(len(VList)):
        if str(MyList[x][0]) == str(VList[y][0]):
            tmpStr = '' #Sets to blank so comparison fails, works because break
            OFile.write(MyList[x][0] + '\n')
            break

        else:
            tmp = str(MyList[x][0])
    if tmp != '': 
        NFile.write(tmp + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
import csv

MYUNITS = 'MyUnits.csv'
VENDORUNITS = 'VendorUnits.csv'
MATCHES = 'Matches.csv'
NONMATCHES = 'NonMatches.csv'

with open(MYUNITS,'r') as MFile, 
(VENDORUNITS,'r') as VFile, 
(MATCHES,'w') as OFile, 
(NONMATCHES,mode,'w') as NFile:

    MyReader = csv.reader(MFile,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
    MyList = list(MyReader)
    MyVals = [x for x in MyList]
    MyVals = [x[0] for x in MyVals]

    VendorReader = csv.reader(VFile,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
    VList = list(VendorReader)
    vVals = [x for x in VList]
    vVals = [x[0] for x in vVals]
    
    

    for val in MyVals:
        if val in vVals:
            OFile.write(Val + '\n')
        else:
            NFile.write(Val + '\n')

    #for x in range(len(MyList)):
    #    for y in range(len(VList)):
    #        if str(MyList[x][0]) == str(VList[y][0]):
    #            OFile.write(MyList[x][0] + '\n')
    #        else:
    #            pass
```

Comment: I will be able to test this again in about 2 hours, in the past using "in" has returned false matches. The dataset I'm working with includes strings that are also detected in larger strings. For example list 1 has value 'a123' that matches list 2 value 'a1234b' because of the in keyword

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way you might go about deduplicating and then writing to a file:

```
import csv

MYUNITS = 'MyUnits.csv'
VENDORUNITS = 'VendorUnits.csv'
MATCHES = 'Matches.csv'
NONMATCHES = 'NonMatches.csv'

list_of_non_matches = []

with open(MYUNITS,mode='r') as MFile,
open(VENDORUNITS,mode='r') as VFile,
open(MATCHES,mode='w') as OFile,
open(NONMATCHES,mode'w') as NFile:

    MyReader = csv.reader(MFile,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
    MyList = list(MyReader)

    VendorReader = csv.reader(VFile,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
    VList = list(VendorReader)

    for x in range(len(MyList)):
        for y in range(len(VList)):
            if str(MyList[x][0]) == str(VList[y][0]):
                OFile.write(MyList[x][0] + '\n')

            else:
                list_of_non_matches.append(MyList[x][0])

    # Remove duplicates from the non matches
    new_list = []
    [new_list.append(x) for x in list_of_non_matches if x not in new_list]
    # Write the new list to a file
    for i in new_list:
        NFile.write(i + '\n')
```